# Seems solved, but why? When connected to remote mysql though some SSH session, it always lost connection in about 5 min ~ 10 min idleness

Tags: mysql, timeout

I have a remote MySQL server. Although the timeout variables are 8 hours. It will lose connection in about 10 minutes. As below. (When the prompt of losing connection comes out, there is a bell sound.)

```
$ mysql -hxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -uxxxxx -p -A
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 35
Server version: 5.7.19-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql> show global variables like '%timeout';
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout      | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout            | 30       |
| net_write_timeout           | 60       |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout           | 60       |
| wait_timeout                | 28800    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%timeout';
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout      | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout            | 30       |
| net_write_timeout           | 60       |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout           | 60       |
| wait_timeout                | 28800    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)
mysql> show databases;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
mysql> show databases;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    597
Current database: *** NONE ***

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| xxxxxxx            |
| xxxxxxx            |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

Update:
Thanks to @scaisEdge's suggestion. I found the strange thing:

I suffer this problem if I connect it in this way:
(1) SSH via SecureCRT on Windows 7 to VMWare VM CentOS 7.3 on this Windows 7
(2) mysql -hxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -uxxxxx -p -A

The problem goes away if I connect it in this way:
(1) SSH via SecureCRT on Windows 7 to VMWare VM CentOS 7.3 on this Windows 7
(2) ssh xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
(3) mysql -hxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -uxxxxx -p -A

Of course, I can change step (3) to:
MySQL -h127.0.0.1 -uxxxxx -p -A

Note: The reason I jump several times is that the MySQL CLI client on Windows platform is not so good as that on Linux.

Although it seems to be solved, it is strange. Why?

Could some expert give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you connected by a webserver???

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, it is a cloud server from Aliyun in China. I mean the MySQL server is on a cloud server (CentOS 7.3) from Aliyun. I connect it from an SSH session on 
 Windows 7 SecureCRT to a VMWare VM (CentOS 7.3) inside the Windows 7 System.

Comment: Are you sure for the session timeout ??

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language, and I am not certain about "are you sure for ...". I mean, I am sure that I always lost it if it is idle for about 5 min ~ 10 min.

Comment: You should check also  if is present a timeout for your  SSH session on Windows 7 SecureCRT

Comment: After I set
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 86400
into the /etc/ssh/sshd_config
of the remote server, the SSH session in my SecureCRT to it seldom lost connection even after long idle.
Can that prove the SSH has no problem?

Comment: Maybe my last comment is confusing. I mean I guess the SSH session may be OK, but the MySQL problem remains unless I firstly SSH the remote server rather than directly use MySQL client in the local Linux environment.